# Admin account that works only for login

Tags: windows-11

I have a problem with administrator account on my Windows 11 laptop. I have set an admin account and it works well - I can use it to login to Windows and perform any administrative tasks.

But when I login to any other non-admin account (regular user), try to install something and then when I'm requested to set the administrative account for elevated privileges it doesn't work - it says "wrong user or password".

So I can login to my admin account but cannot use it for elevated requests from non-admin accounts. Name and password is of course alright.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure User Account Control (UAC) is fully ON and normal. Restart after any changes.

Make sure when you in a Standard Account and are requested for Admin Credentials (a standard Windows dialogue) that you enter the full Admin name (likely a Microsoft Account) and the admin credentials.

Please work carefully. This methodology has been the same for Windows 7, 8, 10 and 11.  It did not change in Windows 11.

If the above does not work, you may need to repair Windows .

Also make and try a new Admin Account to see it that works